# How does $\sqrt{|e^{-y}\cos x + ie^{-y}\sin x|}= e^{-y}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

How does $\sqrt{|e^{-y}\cos x + ie^{-y}\sin x|} = e^{-y}$ which is less than $1$?

This is a step from a question I am doing but I am not sure how the square root equaled & $e^{-y}$

Comment: Do you mean $|e^{-y} \cos x + i e^{-y}\sin x| = e^{-y}$?

Comment: yes this is what i mean but the left hand side of the equation is in a square root

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since
$${e^{ix}} = \cos (x) + i\sin (x)$$
we have
$$\left| {{e^{ix}}} \right| = \sqrt {{{\cos }^2}(x) + {{\sin }^2}(x)} = 1$$
so ...

Comment: As it currently is, the question is wrong, so your answer is at best incomplete.  $\sqrt{|e^{-y}\times ...|} = e^{-y/2}$, not $e^{-y}$.

Answer (score 6):

If

$$z = x + iy$$

then

$$|z| = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

---

Letting $z = e^{-y} \cos x + i e^{-y}\sin x$, we have $\Re (z) = e^{-y} \cos x$ and $\Im (z) = e^{-y}\sin x$.  Assuming $y \in \mathbb R$:

$$|z| = \sqrt{(e^{-y} \cos x)^2 + (e^{-y}\sin x)^2} = \sqrt{e^{-2y} ((\cos x)^2 + (\sin x)^2)} = \sqrt{e^{-2y}} = e^{-y}$$

If you take the square root of both sides, you will see your equality is if fact false.

Answer (score 0):

What is the formula for $|e^{-y}\cos x+ie^{-y}\sin x|$? Do you see any trig identities you can use? The complex number isn't on the unit circle because it's been scaled by $e^{-y}$.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by using properties of the modulus:

$$|e^{-y} \cos x + i e^{-y} \sin x|=|e^{-y}||\cos x + i \sin x|=e^{-y}|e^{ix}|=e^{-y}$$